# How to handle Null in AsyncTask or Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

in my AsyncTask I get an object `Document` for further work with him in the Fragment. the problem is that sometimes I get `document =NULL`. I can catch this exception, but do not know how to handle it. Let's say I got a Null. But what to do next? if I get the data, I form my fragment. but if I get a Null I do not know how to act

My AsyncTask:

```
public class MyAsincTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    private Document document;
    private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyAsincTask(Context context) {
        progressDialog = MyProgress.getProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).timeout(0).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
        super.onPostExecute(document);
    }
}
```

here I form my fragment if the data is received successfully. but what if you came Null?:

```
public void setData() {
        String link = String.format("http://core.android?key=pe=xml", guestid, hotel);
       new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
               super.onPostExecute(document);
               Elements elementsId = document.select("id");
               Elements elementsCheckin = document.select("checkin");
               Elements elementsCheckout = document.select("checkout");
               Elements elementsNights = document.select("nights");

               for (int i = 0; i < elementsId.size(); i++) {
                   HistoryBean historyBean = new HistoryBean();
                   historyBean.setId(elementsId.get(i).ownText());
                   historyBean.setCheckin(elementsCheckin.get(i).ownText());
                   historyBean.setCheckout(elementsCheckout.get(i).ownText());
                   historyBean.setNigth(elementsNights.get(i).ownText());
                   historyBeans.add(historyBean);
               }
               listView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
           }
       }.execute(link);
    }
```

FRAGMENT EXAMPLE:

```
public class Folio extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<FolioBean> folioBeans;
    private TableLayout tableFolio;
    private String guestId;
    private String hotel;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.folio, null);
         guestId = getArguments().getString("guestid");
         hotel = getArguments().getString("hotel");

        folioBeans = new ArrayList<>();
        tableFolio = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tableFolio);
        if (InternetResiver.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            setData();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alert = InternetResiver.getAlertDialog(getActivity());
            alert.show();
        }
        return v;
    }

    public static Folio newInstance(String guestid,String hotel,String room) {
        Folio f = new Folio();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("guestid", guestid);
        b.putString("hotel", hotel);
        b.putString("room", room);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    public void setData() {
        String link = String.format("htype=xml", guestId, hotel);
        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
                super.onPostExecute(document);
                Elements elementsDate = document.select("date");
                Elements elementsName = document.select("name");
                Elements elementsSumm = document.select("summa");

                for (int i = 0; i < elementsName.size(); i++) {
                    FolioBean folioBean = new FolioBean();
                    folioBean.setDate(elementsDate.get(i).ownText());
                    folioBean.setName(elementsName.get(i).ownText());
                    folioBean.setSumm(elementsSumm.get(i).ownText());
                    folioBeans.add(folioBean);
                }
                TableRow.LayoutParams row_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 20f);
                TableRow.LayoutParams row_params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 30f);

                for (FolioBean folioBean : folioBeans) {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(App.get());
                    TextView data = new TextView(App.get());
                    TextView name = new TextView(App.get());
                    TextView summ = new TextView(App.get());
                    data.setTextSize(10);
                    name.setTextSize(10);
                    summ.setTextSize(10);
                    name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    summ.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    data.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    if (folioBean.getName().contains("Проживание")){
                        data.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        summ.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    }
                    data.setText(" " + folioBean.getDate());
                    name.setText(" " + folioBean.getName() + " ");
                    summ.setText(folioBean.getSumm() + " ");
                    tableRow.addView(data, row_params2);
                    tableRow.addView(name, row_params2);
                    tableRow.addView(summ, row_params);
                    tableFolio.addView(tableRow);
                }
            }
        }.execute(link);
    }
}
```

Comment: add `null` check in `onPostExecute` for `document`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a check on document in your onPost() method

```
if (document!=null){

      Elements elementsId = document.select("id");
           Elements elementsCheckin = document.select("checkin");
           Elements elementsCheckout = document.select("checkout");
           Elements elementsNights = document.select("nights");

           for (int i = 0; i < elementsId.size(); i++) {
               HistoryBean historyBean = new HistoryBean();
               historyBean.setId(elementsId.get(i).ownText());
               historyBean.setCheckin(elementsCheckin.get(i).ownText());
               historyBean.setCheckout(elementsCheckout.get(i).ownText());
               historyBean.setNigth(elementsNights.get(i).ownText());
               historyBeans.add(historyBean);
           }
           listView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so. but what if document==null?what will happen?

Comment: when you write this line ( document.select("id"); ) and document is null then will not have element names as id and you will get nullpointerexception

Comment: You do not understand me a little. there are times when I get a Null. I click on the "open fragment" and get Null. and fragment waits the data. but they are not present. I'll write a check to the exclusion did not go, but what do I do with my fragment? I can put on a fragment of any inscription? how to do it? such as "not collected"

Comment: yes you can do it by checking the size of list if the size of list is zero then you can update your fragment accordingly like as you said not collected

Comment: tell me how to do it? I therefore asked the question because I do not understand how it's done. Null if instead of the sheet to show what a message

Comment: i think its simple you can add a check where you are populating fragment if(list.size()==0){Log.e(TAG,"your list is null show not loaded message to user here") //show toast }else{//populate it}

Comment: the fact is that many of these fragments and not everywhere list ... sometimes leaf table, etc.

Comment: @ Moubeen Farooq Khan I added an example fragment

Comment: in your onPost() method firstly have a check that document is not null ,if it is not null that do what your are doing previously, else if it is null then what you can do is is to create dynamic textView and set text to it "not collected " and set that textview to the main view and you are doing previously

Comment: well, I agree that it is not possible to give a universal answer. I know what to do, but not know how) I note your answer as the best, thank you!